# React is editing arrays using logic from other components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been working on this issue for hours but I can't work out what the problem is.

I'm working on a React app which fetches an array of data from an API, but it seems like the array in the component which fetches the data is being affected by a shuffle function in a completely separate component.

It's hard to explain so here's some (simplified, but essentially the same) bits of code:

The fetch bit in Header.js:

```
fetch("https://example.com")
    .then(result => return result.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        this.props.updateData(data)
    })
```

Main.js

```
class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            currentData: []
        }

        this.updateData.bind(this)
    }

    updateData(data) {
        this.setState({currentData: data)}
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Header updateData={this.updateData} />
            <Body data={data} />
        )
    }
}
```

The render bit of Body.js

```
render() {
    return (
        {shuffle(this.props.data).map(item => <p>{item.text}</p>}
    )
}
```

The shuffle() function

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}
```

The console.log in **header.js** sends the value of shuffle(data) to the console when that should only be run in **body.js** after being passed through **main.js**

Sorry if it makes no sense but I have searched for ages and I need to move on soon

Thanks in advance <3

Comment: if you remove the call to `shuffle()` in the `<Body />` is the `console.log()` in `<Header />` as expected? seems like it might be a reference issue

Comment: how about `shuffle(this.props.data.map(item => <p>{item.text}</p>))`

Comment: And you have multiple syntax errors in your snippets, like `result => return ...` or missing `)`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `shuffle()` function is shuffling the array in place, meaning it's updating `this.props.data` rather than making a separate, shuffled version of it. It's generally a bad idea to update the values of any `props` or `state` directly, because it can cause weird issues like this.

If you want to have the `shuffle` function return a shuffled copy, you can add the line `array = array.slice()` at the top of that function.

If you'd rather leave `shuffle` as it is you could alternatively use `shuffle(this.props.data.slice()).map(...)` or `shuffle(this.props.data.map(...))` since both of these create new arrays *before* shuffling them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it fixed the problem. I was just wondering, why does React do this? It would (sort of) make sense at one level, updating the props of the body object, but I find it extremely strange that it updates the state of the main object, which updates the data object received by the fetch function in header. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Yeah, it can be a bit confusing to keep track of this kind of thing. This is more of a Javascript issue than a React one, honestly. When you pass down the Array `this.data` as a prop to `Body`, you're passing down a reference to the array rather than a copy of the array, so anything you do directly to `this.props.data` in `Body` affects the referenced array rather than a new one. This is the same as if you were to run something like: `let arr1 = [1,2,3]; let arr2 = arr1; arr2[0] = 'abc'; console.log(arr1[0]); // 'abc'` since both `arr1` and `arr2` are referring to the *literal same* array.